# Redistribute array proportionally

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array containing some email addresses that is divided by domain.

I'd like to "redistribute" the array, proportioned by addresses num in that domain, due to the reason that I want to send emails to domains "proportinally".

Example:

```
$original_haystack = array
(
    '@hotmail.com' => array
    (
        'user1@hotmail.com',
        'user2@hotmail.com',
        'user3@hotmail.com',
        'user4@hotmail.com'
    ),
    '@gmail.com' => array
    (
        'user1@gmail.com',
        'user2@gmail.com'
    ),
    '@foobar.com' => array
    (
        'user1@foobar.com'
    )
);

$result_haystack = array
(
    'user1@hotmail.com',
    'user2@hotmail.com',
    'user1@gmail.com',
    'user1@foobar.com',
    'user3@hotmail.com',
    'user4@hotmail.com',
    'user2@gmail.com'
);
```

Comment: Why does the output order matter? If you're sending a load of emails, they'll still be sent "roughly" at the same time

Comment: Because the real array contains 20000 records that are sended in a delayed mode... between first send and last send occurs hours.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. How do you get to send 2xhotmail, then 1xgmail, then 1xfoobar ?

Comment: Total e-mails: 7

 - hotmail.com: 4 emails (in proportion on other e-mails, i can split domain in 2 blocks of 2 addresses, called for example "h1" and "h2")

 - gmail.com: 2 emails (in proportion on other e-mails, i can split domain in 2 blocks of 1 address, called for example "g1" and "g2")

 - foobar: 1 email (only 1 element, i'll put it between first serie of block "hotmail.com" and "gmail.com",  this "block" is called for example "f1")


 ---- After this logic, i have these proportioned blocks: h1 + g1 + f1 + h2 + g2 so that each domain is more possible distant than the other one.